# Grafana embed range selector in html website

Tags: javascript, html, grafana, graphite

I have included a grafana graph in my html website with an iframe

```
<iframe src="http://mysourceaddress:3000/d-solo/-J_QBsFMz/dash?orgId=1&panelId=8" width="450" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

It works but is it possible to embed the range selector too? For example to show only data from yesterday or the last month and so on...

Thank you!

Best regards